# Puppeteer Sharp: setting a fake path when loading content?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I'm using the 
`page.SetContentAsync(myHtml);`
method in Puppeteer Sharp to load some HTML that is not hosted on any server.

Unfortunately, in my HTML I need to use a JS script (which I cannot easily modify), that relies on the `location.pathname` value to contain at least one slash `/` (it does some parsing on it), otherwise it crashes.

Is there any way, either through Puppeteer itself or simple JavaScript, to override/fake the value of `location.pathname`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use disable the same-origin policy using [`--disable-web-security`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-web-security) and then use [`history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) to replace the current entry in the browser's history.

This will change the value of `location.pathname` without causing a page redirect.

Consider the following example:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require( 'puppeteer' );

( async () =>
{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        'args' : [
            '--disable-web-security'
        ]
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    let pathname = await page.evaluate( () =>
    {
        const fake_pathname = '/example/index.php';

        history.replaceState( null, null, 'http://_' + fake_pathname );

        return location.pathname;
    });

    console.log( pathname ); // /example/index.php

    await page.setContent( /* ... */ );

    // Perform your task ...

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work on pages that don't already have a a URL, I get the error: `Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL '' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'about:blank'`

Comment: @Master_T This is due to the same-origin policy. You can `--disable-web-security` to allow for the solution to work. See updated answer.